# After deleting numbers from my list my "for loop" doesn't do what I want

Tags: python-3.x

On my second attempt after deleting the first three digits in my list does the "for loop" not seem to accept my deleted numbers, instead it formats it in some way that I do not understand. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

```
nums = [3,3,1,3,2,5,6,3]
#iterating through list
total = 0
for number in nums:
    total+=number
print ("sum of all values in list: ",total)
print("sum of all values in list: ", sum(nums))
print (len(nums))

del nums[0:3] #deletes [3,3,1]
for number in nums:
    total+=number
print ("sum of all values in list: ",total)
print("sum of all values in list: ", sum(nums))
print (len(nums))
```

Result:

```
sum of all values in list:  26
sum of all values in list:  26
8
sum of all values in list:  45
sum of all values in list:  19
5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What is this "format that you don't understand"? Is it because `total` is too high? (Because you forget to set it to zero.)

Comment: btw, use `sum(nums)` :-)

Comment: @usr2564301  Thanks, that aswerd my question. Thank you for helping me understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nums = [3,3,1,3,2,5,6,3]
total = 0
for number in nums:
    total+=number
print ("sum of all values in list: ",total)`

total has the value 26

`del nums[0:3]`

you deleted [3,3,1] from nums which turned the list as [3, 2, 5, 6, 3] now

`for number in nums:
    total+=number
print ("sum of all values in list: ",total)`

total is not reset to 0 and hence total gives you 26+3+2+5+6+3 = 45

`print("sum of all values in list: ", sum(nums))`

since the list is now [3, 2, 5, 6, 3] after deletion of first 3 entries, sum(nums) gives  3 + 2 + 5 + 6 + 3 = 19

Hope that helped:)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot :)